# ContentTools: how do I focus the first editable region when start editing?

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg

How do I focus the first editable region when start editing? I can't seem to find a focus() method.

Comment: What do you mean the first editable region? Create a working example...

Comment: If you are familiar with ContentTools, there are multiple regions that can be made editable within a document (available as ContentTools.EditorApp.get().regions()). I need to set the focus on one of them from code.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that, but if you will create a working example I can take a look, and other people here might be able to help as well

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for `ContentTools.EditorApp.get().orderedRegions()`, this returns a list of the regions in their (by default) order provided or discovered on page. You can then write something along the lines of:

```
function focusFirst(ev) {
    var regions = ContentTools.EditorApp.get().orderedRegions();
    console.log(regions);
    regions[0].children[0].focus();
}
ContentTools.EditorApp.get().addEventListener('started', focusFirst);
```